# How to write reproduction health data in google fit?

Tags: google-fit

I'm trying to read reproductive health data (menstrual flow) from google fit api for android but I can't test it as there is currently no data to read, so I decided to write the data in the app but It isn't going well. Here is my code: 
I'm getting error on setDataType(HealthDataTypes.TYPE_MENSTRUATION): must set data source type

```
        DataSource menstruationSource = new DataSource.Builder()
        .setDataType(HealthDataTypes.TYPE_MENSTRUATION)
        .build();
        DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(menstruationSource);
        DataPoint bloodPressure = DataPoint.builder(menstruationSource)
        .setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .setField(HealthFields.FIELD_MENSTRUAL_FLOW, HealthFields.MENSTRUAL_FLOW_MEDIUM)
        .build();
        dataSet.add(bloodPressure);
        Object dataReadResult = Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(googleFitManager.getGoogleApiClient(), dataSet);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's saying that you need to set the type of the data source (*not just* the data type):

```
new DataSource.Builder()
      .setDataType(HealthDataTypes.TYPE_MENSTRUATION)
      .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)  // <-- THIS
```

(I'm not claiming this is sufficient to create it; merely, that's what the error message is saying you should do).

---

But, [menstruation is a restricted data type](https://developers.google.com/fit/datatypes/restricted). In order to be able to access these data types, your app needs to be specially verified.

As the note says:

> Google has temporarily stopped taking new requests to write to restricted data types. We are updating our policy and process for reviewing requests and will update this documentation again when we resume.

Comment: Yes you're right, I did added that but it still doesn't show anything on google fit app after successful call. I used the same structure for adding blood pressure data which is also a restricted health data type and it worked well.

Comment: Here's my code for menstrual cycle:

DataSource source = new DataSource.Builder()
        .setDataType(HealthDataTypes.TYPE_MENSTRUATION)
        .setAppPackageName(GoogleFitPackage.PACKAGE_NAME)
        .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
        .build();
DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(source);
DataPoint point = dataSet.createDataPoint().setTimestamp(time, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
point.getValue(HealthFields.FIELD_MENSTRUAL_FLOW).setInt(HealthFields.MENSTRUAL_FLOW_MEDIUM);
dataSet.add(point);
Object result = Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(googleFitManager.getGoogleApiClient(), dataSet);

Answer (score 0):

permissions have changed:

https://developers.google.com/fit/datatypes/health#getting_permission_to_read_and_write_health_data

"Note: If your app isn't verified when it requests access to a sensitive OAuth scope, Google will assess its risk and apply quotas accordingly. Your users might also see warning screens. You can still test your app but the quotas will restrict how many new users you can get."